# open source workflow engine project based on wf 4+

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

its any open source workflow engine project that based on wf 4+ ?

I have already seen [Windows Workflow (WF) Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page , but i need another complete sample

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for

Answer (score 3):

There is a rehosting sample called "Workflow Studio" available here: [Workflow Studio for WF 4.5](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Workflow-Studio-for-WF-45-90aa0998). There is also a blog entry: [Workflow Foundation (WF4) – Rehosting The Workflow Designer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2012/03/26/workflow-foundation-wf4-rehosting-the-workflow-designer.aspx)

> a simple, generic application that allows you to design and execute
>   multiple XAML based workflows in a windowed environment akin with
>   Visual Studio. Use it to design and test your workflows in
>   environments where Visual Studio is not the right tool. You can even
>   use it as a simple hosting environment. I’ve developed Workflow Studio
>   as an application you can use out of the box, or you can use it as the
>   basis for your own specialised implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Why would there be an open source workflow engine based on WF 4? Windows workflow and the samples provide a great starting point. See the latest features in 4.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781025.aspx